# Insert image into database in python mysql

Tags: python, mysql, database, opencv

I want to insert an image into database which is opened in OpenCV project as "cv2.imshow" window. And also I want to reload image in OpenCV. I'm using Python, PyQT5 and MySQL for this task. I was able to connect with MySQL database using pymysql package. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Actually I want to know a method to save the OpenCV output window image into the database. In OpenCV can write image using "cv2.imwrite" in a given directory. Like that I want to save it in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can save your image into database using `LONGBLOB` datatype.

But it isn't smart way. I suggest you save your images into a directory (or online) and save their URL only.

Comment: Yes I know that LONGBLOB is the datatype which should used to store images. I had insert some data to my table and could view when I run the code. But it gives me binary code of the image. And I want a way to save my output window image in database.

Comment: @DenukaNirmalee you can also parse your binary code into image by this way `Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
imageView.setImageBitmap(image);`